# Unable to create google-services.json

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-signin

I tried clicking **GET A CONFIGURATION FILE** link from the [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get-config), I provided my android project name and the android package name from the manifest.xml of my android app. But, still it is throwing an error ***Project name is invalid. Ensure that the name has no special characters and is within 4 to 30 characters***. My name neither has any special charecter no it is longer than 30.

Attaching a screenshot for a better understanding.[image]

Comment: com.example will not work. Please use com.somename.home.googlesignindemo

Comment: @AshishPardhiye: Nopes, tried that. no luck. strange thing is it is taking a string of 16 'a's successfully as name, GsignInDemo and com.examle.test.gsignindemo as name and packagename, but not googlesignindemo as name. strange!!

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

your app name contains "google" word. Remove this then try.

Comment: Well, Is there any mention of not using Google in documentation? Please provide  if you find any. Strangely, whenever I am removing the google keyword from the project name it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i encountered the same problem , in my case i just create a new project name instead of choosing from existing project and it works.

Comment: I have tried this also but still no luck. I am getting the same error.

Comment: i don't know why above name is giving error  but when i choose DemoLogin has created successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The package name listed about is longer than 30 characters. The error message states that package names must be between 4 and 30 character.

Comment: Not really I think, Changed the name from Google to ABCDEF, and it worked successfully.